# In Rails 4, how do I overcome "Argument can't be converted to a class" when trying to query by a field of a field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations, finder

I’m using Rails 4.2.10.  I have the following models …

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
…
    has_many :products


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manufacturer
```

However, when I want to search for orders with matching manufacturers of a particular name, I get this error ...

```
> o = Order.includes(products: :manufacturer).where(:manufacturer => {:name => n})
ArgumentError: manufacturer can't be converted to a class
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@cfs-web/bundler/gems/squeel-c48618090f47/lib/squeel/adapters/active_record/context.rb:59:in `classify'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@cfs-web/bundler/gems/squeel-c48618090f47/lib/squeel/visitors/visitor.rb:9:in `classify'
```

How do I properly search for records when the clause is a field of a field?

Comment: I think it's supposed to be `.where(:manufacturers => {:name => n})`

Comment: I got the same error when I converted it to plural -- "manufacturers can't be converted to a class"

Comment: Hm, maybe this hash syntax doesn't work in that old version. Try the sql version, something like `.where("manufacturers.name = ?", n)`. This guide could be useful: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: This fails with "Unknown column 'manufacturers.name'".  The SQL that is generated doesn't include any of the join tables, interstingly enough.

Comment: That _is_ interesting. Well, I hope you solve it. I have no more ideas off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter results based on an association in a where clause, you need to use `joins` instead of (or in addition to) `includes`:

```rb
o = Order.joins(products: :manufacturer).where(:manufacturers => {:name => n})
```

Comment: It should be `:manufacturers => {:name => n}` because it will be the table name.

Comment: Good catch @MarlinPierce! I updated the answer to use the plural `:manufacturers`.